# Is there a way to view files in Azure Static Web App?

Tags: azure-static-web-app

Is there a way to view the files uploaded to Azure Static Web App using Azure Portal? I need to check few items. I can see the file in my DevOps Repo but want to confirm it is located in the correct folder structure in Azure Static Web App. Please note that this is not Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 2):

Right now (at least for Free SKU) it is not possible to view files like it was for Static Website inside Blob storage when you go to $web container. But you can see connected source that is Azure DevOps in my case, as well as deployment history.

See image with explanation: [Static web app information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMXOg.jpg)

Comment: Tried for standard Sku, but still can't find a way to view deployed files. The source link just redirects to my Code Repository.
I need a way to see the actual deployed files, using the DevOps pipeline task: AzureStaticWebApp

Comment: I can see those files because I do building (and running tests + static code analysis before) and publish artifacts before deployment using task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1 and then deployment from that location -> app_location: "./clientApp"

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old question, I still had this problem when someone wanted this functionality for one of our apps. In our instance, we're simply hosting static files in the default $web container of the storage account. One of our developers asked if it was possible to have directorty browsing, like we did when we previously hosted these files with Apache?

I tried many different things but couldn't make anything stick. Maybe it's my abilities, maybe it's by design, but after spending almost a day trying to make it work - I ended up with a simple, but somewhat dirty hack.

During the Azure Devops pipeline I use to build and create the artifact, I install the Linux tool "tree".

Lets simply call the folder that contains our code, "code".
I created a script that runs after the code has been built and it's ready for packaging.
It contains this simple command: find . -type d -exec tree -H . -o  '{}/tree.html' ;

https://example.com/tree.html contains the tree structure of the published app.

It's not pretty, but it serves the purpose of listing the structure and containing files.