# Where can I see the files for a Azure static web app? Image file doesn't seem to have been deployed

Tags: azure, web, static, blazor

I'm playing around with Azure Static Web Apps and have built a simple Blazor App which I've deployed. I added a Contacts page with an image that appears when built and running in Visual Studio but the image is missing when the app is is deployed via a GitHub Workflow Action. I've checked the file is present in the GitHub repo. I'm just using the free version of Azure static web apps for testing and believe the files are deployed to blob storage.

I can see two similar related questions to my problem but neither of them provide a solution to my issue

[Is there a way to view files in Azure Static Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68684821/is-there-a-way-to-view-files-in-azure-static-web-app)

[Azure static web apps not loading page resources correctly. css or javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254772/azure-static-web-apps-not-loading-page-resources-correctly-css-or-javascript-fi)

As per the link to the first question above, is there a way to see the files deployed to check if the file is actually there? Everything I'm seeing tells me it's not! - the image is not showing and copying the link to a new window gives me the usual file not found. Link looks absolutely spot on - https://madeupbit.azurestaticapps.net/FundXWebTelNo1.png. I deliberately moved the file out of a separate images directory into the root to eliminate any of the possible issues mentioned in the second question linked above.

And I guess the second question is if it's not there, how do I get it there seeing the automated GitHub Workflow Action ain't doing it. Of course there may be something else going  on so any suggestions welcome!

Comment: I had this issue. I don't have a direct answer to the question but I shifted my static content to a blob store and used a fully qualified path to the blob store and this is working Ok.